# abstract javascript code into ES6 function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have some code that is working but I want to abstract it into a functional component I can use elsewhere in my script. I am getting an undefined error:

This works:

```
//add an index to each element
    var items = learning_check.map(function(el,i) {
      var o = Object.assign({}, el);
      o.key = i;
      return o;
    });
```

this doesn't:

```
const addIndex = (a) => {
  console.log('addIndex initiated')
  a.map = (el,i) => {
    var o = Object.assign({}, el);
    o.key = i;
    return o;
  }
}
```

called with

```
const mItems = addIndex(learning_check); // initiated
console.log('mItems: ' + mItems); // undefined
```

Comment: You're not `return`ing the result of the `map` - `addIndex` has no `return` statement.

Comment: In your second code block you aren't calling map, you are overwriting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I'd like to say that you're on the right track. You're missing two things.

You need to call `map` and not reassign it, like `a.map(...)` and not `a.map = ...`. And, you need to return the result of `map` from your `addIndex` function. Like so,

```js
const addIndex = (a) => {
  console.log('addIndex initiated');
  // Notice the return
  return a.map((el, i) => { // See how we call map here
    var o = Object.assign({}, el);
    o.key = i;
    return o;
  });
}

// Mock
const learning_check = [{
  id: "abcde"
}, {
  id: "fghij"
}];

const mItems = addIndex(learning_check); // initiated
console.log('mItems: ' + JSON.stringify(mItems));
```

I'll suggest a simplification to your code here, you could use it if you like

```js
const addIndex = (a) => {
  console.log('addIndex initiated')
  return a.map((el, i) => Object.assign({
    key: i
  }, el));
}

// Mock
const learning_check = [{
  id: "abcde"
}, {
  id: "fghij"
}];

const mItems = addIndex(learning_check); // initiated
console.log('mItems: ' + JSON.stringify(mItems));
```

Comment: This works very well and thank you for the explanation I understand now

Answer (score 1):

Two bugs in your code
1) You are not returning anything from the function.
2) You are not calling the `map` function.

```
const addIndex = (a) => {
  console.log('addIndex initiated')
  return a.map((el, i) => {
    var o = Object.assign({}, el);
    o.key = i;
    return o;
  })
}
```